# Limit the items shown in a ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code to limit the number of visible list items in a `ul`:

```
$wnd.$(el)
    .find('li:gt(9)')
    .hide()
    .end()
    .append(
    $wnd.$('<li>+More</li>').click( function(){
        $wnd.$(this).siblings(':hidden').show().end().remove();
    })
);
```

When `+More` is clicked it will show all the items immediately.

What should be added in the code such when `+More` is clicked it will not show everything yet, just the next 10 items? Then, when all items are shown, a `+Less` option should be shown to just show the first 10 items, as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange syntax, but something like this maybe

```
$wnd.$(el)
    .find('li:gt(9)')
    .hide()
    .end()
    .append(
        $wnd.$('<li>+More</li>').click(function () {
            $wnd.$(this).remove().siblings(':hidden').slice(0, 10).show();

            if ($wnd.$(el).find('li:hidden').length === 0) {
                $wnd.$(el).append(
                    $wnd.$('<li>+Less</li>').click(function () {
                        $wnd.$(el).find('li:gt(9)').hide();
                    })
                )
            }
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
    $( 'li:gt(9)' )
        .hide()
        .parent()
        .append( 
            $( '<li>more</li>' ).on( 'click', function() {              
                var el = $( this ).siblings( ':hidden' );

                if ( el.length ) el.slice( 0, 10 ).show();                  
                else $( 'li:gt(9)' ).not( this ).hide();

                $( this ).text( $( this ).siblings( ':hidden' ).length ? 'more' : 'less' );                 
            })
         );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztke99m2/)

Comment: Your code looks good, however how can I adapt it to $(el) as the first query my code can do it that

Answer (score 0):

How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/0hyL9ngr/

HTML

```
<ul id='some-list'>
  <li class='list-item'>1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>3</li>
  ...
  <li class='list-item'>39</li>
  <li class='list-item'>40</li>
  <li class='list-item'>41</li>
  <li id='show-more'>More</li>
  <li id='show-first-ten'>Less</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#show-more').on('click', function () {
  $('.list-item:hidden:lt(10)').show();
  if ($('.list-item:hidden').length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#show-first-ten').show();
  }
});

$('#show-first-ten').on('click', function () {
  $('.list-item:gt(9)').hide();
  $(this).hide();
  $('#show-more').show();
});
```

CSS

```
#show-more {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#show-first-ten {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-item:nth-child(n+11) {
  display: none;
}
```